# How to call class A method inside class B method in Python

Tags: python, class, methods

I currently face a problem when I want to call a class A method inside a class B method. The code is running fine. However, the problem happen at line 73 in **ImageProcessing.py** where **MainApplication.signup()** is asking for parameter. This function is built for returning to the signup page. I am not sure if it is the right way to code like this. Please help me. I would appreciate your kindness.

*This is Display.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import ImageProcessing

class MainApplication:
    def __init__(self,master): # parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        # Resize image
        self.open_image = Image.open('images/log_icon.png')
        self.resized_image = self.open_image.resize((170, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        # Define image
        self.img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_image)
        self.bg1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/darkblue.png'))
        self.lock = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('Icon/lock.ico'))
        self.loginBtn = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/login-button.png'))

        # Create labels and buttons
        self.my_label = Label(master, image=self.bg1)
        self.my_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        self.log_head = Label(master, image=self.img, bg="#1f1a30")
        self.log_head.place(x=115, y=10)

        self.lock_label = Label(master, image=self.lock, bg="#39304d")
        self.lock_label.place(x=50, y=200, height=35, width=40)

        self.username = Entry(master, font=("arial", 13), bg="#39304d", fg="white", borderwidth=0)
        self.username.place(x=90, y=200, width=250, height=35)

        self.login_btn = Button(master, image=self.loginBtn, borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30", activebackground="#1f1a30", command=self.login)
        self.login_btn.place(x=35, y=300)

        self.signup_label = Label(master, text="Don't have an account?", bg="#1f1a30", font=("times new roman", 10),
                             fg="white")
        self.signup_label.place(x=110, y=380)

        self.signup_btn = Button(master, text="Sign Up", borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30", font=("times new roman", 10, "underline"),
                             fg="#0df6e3", activebackground="#1f1a30", command=self.signup)
        self.signup_btn.place(x=240, y=380)

        self.forget_btn = Button(master, text="Forgot Your Password?", borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30",
                            font=("times new roman", 10),
                            fg="#0df6e3", activebackground="#1f1a30")
        self.forget_btn.place(x=132, y=410)


    def signup(self):
        def open(filename):
            os.chdir("C:\Python Projects\PyFYP")  # file path
            os.system('python ' + filename)  # run the python command on cmd to execute both windows

        self.master.destroy()
        open("Registration.py")

    def login(self):
        pass

def main_login():
    App = tk.Tk()
    App.title("Login")
    App.iconbitmap('C:/Python Projects/PyFYP/Icon/snake2.ico')
    App.resizable(False, False)

    # Put TK Window screen to center
    app_width = 390
    app_height = 500

    screen_width = App.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = App.winfo_screenheight()

    sys_width = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    sys_height = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    App.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(sys_width)}+{int(sys_height)}')
    MainApplication(App)
    App.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_login()
```

*This is ImageProcessing.py

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
import Display


class ProcessImage():
    def __init__(self, master):  # parent, *args, **kwargs):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = tk.Frame(self.master)

        self.bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/neon.png'))
        self.Upload_Btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/upload_btn.png'))
        self.proceed_Btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/proceed_btn.png'))
        self.cancel_Btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/cancel_btn.png'))
        self.reset_Btn_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('images/reset_btn.png'))

        # Labels and Buttons
        self.Img_process_background = tk.Label(master, image=self.bg)
        self.Img_process_background.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        # OpenCV window name
        self.windowName = "Selected Image"

        # Attributes for setting coordinates
        self.coordinate = np.zeros((3, 2), int)
        self.counter = 0
        self.file_path_name = "" # Uploaded image's file path

        # Upload Image label
        self.uploadImg_label = Label(master, text="Please upload your preference image here.", bg="#1f1a30", font=("arial", 12, "bold"), fg="white")
        self.uploadImg_label.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.uploadImg_note = Label(master, text="* Only jpg, jpeg, png, are allowed.", bg="#1f1a30", font=("arial", 8, "bold"), fg="grey")
        self.uploadImg_note.place(x=50, y=75)
        self.img_resize_note = Label(master, text="* Image will be resize to 900x500.", bg="#1f1a30",font=("arial", 8, "bold"), fg="grey")
        self.img_resize_note.place(x=50, y=100)
        self.txt_uploadImg = Entry(master, font=("arial", 10), bg="#39304d", fg="white", borderwidth=0)
        self.txt_uploadImg.place(x=50, y=125, width=350, height=20)

        # Create Buttons
        self.upload_btn = tk.Button(master, image=self.Upload_Btn_img, command=self.Browsing, borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30",activebackground="#1f1a30")
        self.upload_btn.place(x=170, y=175, width=120)

        self.reset_Btn = Button(master, command=self.reset_it, image=self.reset_Btn_img, borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30",activebackground="#1f1a30")
        self.reset_Btn.place(x=80, y=250, width=120)

        self.cancel_btn = Button(master, command=self.cancel_it, image=self.cancel_Btn_img, borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30",activebackground="#1f1a30")
        self.cancel_btn.place(x=260, y=250, width=120)

        self.proceed_btn = Button(master, image=self.proceed_Btn_img, borderwidth=0, bg="#1f1a30",activebackground="#1f1a30", command=self.SetCoordinates)
        self.proceed_btn.place(x=170, y=400, width=120)



    def reset_it(self):
        self.counter = 0
        self.txt_uploadImg.delete(0, "end")
        self.file_path_name = ""
        messagebox.showinfo(title="Success", message="Points have been reset")


    def cancel_it(self):
        # Initialize variables
        self.master.destroy()
        self.counter = 0
        self.file_path_name = ""
        MainApplication.signup() # Return to sign up/register page



    def SetCoordinates(self):
        try:
            self.read_img = cv2.imread(self.file_path_name) # read image
            self.resized_img = cv2.resize(self.read_img, (900,500))

            while True:
                cv2.namedWindow(self.windowName)
                cv2.imshow(self.windowName, self.resized_img)
                cv2.setMouseCallback(self.windowName, self.PassPoints)
                cv2.waitKey(1)

                if self.counter == 3:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    messagebox.showinfo(title="Success", message="Points were marked successfully")
                    cv2.destroyWindow(self.windowName)
                    break
        except:
            messagebox.showerror(title="Error message", message="Image not found")
            cv2.destroyWindow(self.windowName)


    def PassPoints(self, event, x, y, flags, params):
        global counter

        if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:

            self.coordinate[self.counter] = x, y
            colorsB = self.resized_img[y, x, 0]
            colorsG = self.resized_img[y, x, 1]
            colorsR = self.resized_img[y, x, 2]
            self.counter += 1
            print("x= " + str(x) + " y= " + str(y))
            print('Red: ' + str(colorsR) + ' ' + 'Green: ' + str(colorsG) + ' ' + 'Blue: ' + str(colorsB))



    def Browsing(self):
        img_file = filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r', filetypes=[('JPEG', '*.jpeg'), ('JPEG', '*.jpg'), ('PNG', '*.png')])
        global file_path_name

        def setImageNameInput(self, text):
            self.txt_uploadImg.delete(0, "end")
            self.txt_uploadImg.insert(0, text)

        # img_file.name: the .name used to get the file path of the uploaded image
        if img_file:
            setImageNameInput(self,img_file.name)
            self.file_path_name = img_file.name

def main_image_process():
    Imageprocess_page = tk.Tk()
    Imageprocess_page.title("Image processing")
    Imageprocess_page.iconbitmap('C:/Python Projects/PyFYP/Icon/snake2.ico')
    Imageprocess_page.resizable(False, False)

    app_width = 900
    app_height = 500

    screen_width = Imageprocess_page.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = Imageprocess_page.winfo_screenheight()

    sys_width = (screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2)
    sys_height = (screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2)
    Imageprocess_page.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{int(sys_width)}+{int(sys_height)}')
    ProcessImage(Imageprocess_page)
    Imageprocess_page.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_image_process()
```

*This is the error
**TypeError: signup() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**

Comment: can you please add the stacktrace of the error you are receiving in the question? Doing so will help people to understand the nature of the error and how to best fix.

Comment: Yes. I have added the stacktrace of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call the method, because it is not a **static / class method** but instead the method of an **instance / object** of the class **MainApplication**.

This means that the `cancel_it` method's parameter `self` expects an instance of the class `MainApplication` to function properly but by calling `MainApplication.cancel_it()` it receives the **class instead** as argument and **therefore throws an exception**.

You could easily call it, by passing a **reference** to the **Mainapplication-instance** to your **cancel_it** method.

Assuming that:

```
self.master
```

in the `ProcessImage` classe's `__init__` method is a reference to the **Main-Application instance**, the solution would look like this:

```
  def cancel_it(self):
        # Initialize variables
        self.master.destroy()
        self.counter = 0
        self.file_path_name = ""
        self.master.signup() # Return to sign up/register page
```

Otherwise, the method-adjustment might look something like this:

```
def cancel_it(self, main_application):
    # Initialize variables
    self.master.destroy()
    self.counter = 0
    self.file_path_name = ""
    main_application.signup() # Return to sign up/register page
```

with `main_application` being the reference to the MainApplication, which would have to passed as argument.
If the latter case should be true - Keep in mind that you will also have to adjust the `command` of the button responsible for calling the function, so that it actually passes the argument `main_application`.

Comment: @EdmondNg yes, I've updated my answer

Comment: It seems like some parts of your code are missing, if you share the rest of it I can give you a more concrete implementation

Comment: For instance, what is "self.master" in Processimage's __init__ method? Is it a reference to the MainApplication instance?

Comment: Hi @Bialomazur,
It shows an error when I modify the command as command=self.MainApplication.cancel_it()

Comment: @EdmondNg updated the answer again, but please tell us whether self.master references MainApplication's instance or not.

Comment: I have already shared everything. 
I think the master is referring to the tkinter frame?

Comment: I see, I will update the answer once more, you will have to change quite a few aspects of the code

Comment: May I know how should I adjust the command ? currently is "command=self.cancel_it". If I follow the second solution you provide

Comment: Adjusting the command won't fix it in this case - first you have to either create an instance of MainApplication inside your main-method in ImageProcessing.py or pass it to the main_image_process function

Comment: Can you show me how to solve this?
Because I'm not very sure. I am still a beginner.

Comment: @EdmondNg I'm sorry, I went afk and was unable to respond to further questions from your side - still I'm happy that it works for you now! I would really appreciate it if you upvoted & accepted my response, best regards